# MATLAB: get min x value of struct of vectors

Tags: matlab, struct

I have a struct with a field called positions containing vectors.
e.g.:

```
mystruct(1) = struct('position', [1,3,3])
mystruct(2) = struct('position', [2,2,0])
mystruct(3) = struct('position', [3,1,-3])
```

and without using a for loop i want to get the min x, y and z position
-> [1,1,-3]

is that possible?

Comment: "without using a for loop" If these vectors are large and/or there are many of them, creating the intermediate array that allows you to do this operation without a loop will be much more expensive than using a loop. Don't be afraid of loops, and always compare the time of your vectorized approach to the plain old loop for a meaningful use case before deciding on which one is faster. You will be surprised many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try `vertcat` like below

```
>> min(vertcat(mystruct.position),[],1)
ans =

   1   1  -3
```

where

```
>> vertcat(mystruct.position)
ans =

   1   3   3
   2   2   0
   3   1  -3`
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to [get the struct field as a vector](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/248143-how-to-get-struct-array-field-as-a-vector)

```
positions = [mystruct.position]
% positions: [1   3   3   2   2   0   3   1  -3]
```

Then, [reshape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) that vector to `Nx3`. Giving an empty array for the number of rows tells MATLAB to calculate the number of rows automatically so that we have three columns:

```
positions = reshape(positions, [], 3)
% positions: 
%   1   2   3
%   3   2   1
%   3   0  -3
```

Then, find the [rowwise minimum](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html#d123e857011).

```
result = min(positions, [], 2)
% result: 
%   1
%   1
%  -3
```